# How to fix Cloud Firestore returning empty array?

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve data from a Firestore collection in PHP. When I `var_dump $document->data()`, it returns `array(0)`.

[image: Firestore DB]

PHP output:

> Document data for document DEV:
>
> array(0) {
>
> }

```php
$collection = $this->db->collection('environment/DEV/shipments');
if (!empty($where)) {
    //$query = $this->_where_chain($collection, $where);
    $documents = $collection->documents();
    var_dump($documents);
    foreach ($documents as $document) {
        var_dump($document);
        if ($document->exists()) {
            printf('Document data for document %s:' . PHP_EOL, $document->id());
            var_dump($document->data());
            printf(PHP_EOL);
        } else {
            printf('Document %s does not exist!' . PHP_EOL, $snapshot->id());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug with the dynamical collection name (it was different than the code sample above), make sure the $this->db->collection('COLLECTION_NAME'); is correct.